# how to split a string based on delimiter in go html template

Tags: html, split

I am using go html templates for alerting through bosun using prometheus queries .
Below is the use case in my promql result I get instance name as instancename:9100 (example - xyz.com:9100) while setting up alerts I just need xyz.com , below is the snippet that I used using split function but that is not working . can someone please help here

**result from promql would be like below**

```
{dc="IN",env="production",instance="xyz.com:9100",job="node-exporter",service="test"}
```

**code snippet used using go html templates**

```
        <table style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td><b>Host</b></td>
        <td><b>Used Memory (%)</b></td>


    {{ range $v := .LeftJoin .Alert.Vars.result .Alert.Vars.result}}
    {{ $res := index $v 0 }}


        <td>{{(split ":" $res.Group.instance)._0 }}</td>
        <td>{{$res.Group.value}}</td>
        {{
        <td>
```